# MySQL: Binary geometry function st_contains given two geometries of different srids: 4326 and 0

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-8

I attempted to select a city and/or districts by using the `Point`-data type in MySQL, using Laravel.

The query looks like:

```sql
SELECT id, bounding_box 
FROM `districts` 
WHERE ST_Contains(ST_GeomFromText('Point(-96.505144 41.322207)', 4326), bounding_box)
```

##### `districts` table

- id
- name
- bounding_box

This gives me an exception: `Binary geometry function st_contains given two geometries of different srids: 4326 and 0, which should have been identical.`.

When I remove the SRID from `ST_GeomFromText` within the query, the exception gives me a reversed order of SRID in the exception:

> Binary geometry function st_contains given two geometries of different srids: 0 and 4326, which should have been identical.

I used `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON` to parse my polygon. The MySQL documentation for `ST_GeomFromGeoJSON()` tells me the default SRID used is 4326.

Using `ST_Transform()` on my bounding_box gives me the exception: `Transformation from SRID 0 is not supported.`, but I don't understand why it's SRID 0, when the default for importing is 4326.

How can I correctly use `ST_Contains` to query my table for districts based on a `Point`-data type? I get the same behaviour when using `ST_Within`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out.

I added `"crs":{"type":"name","properties":{"name":"EPSG:4326"}}` to the GeoJSON polygon I was hydrating the DB with.